# no notification with flutter_local_notification when build APK

Tags: flutter, dart

i set my app to get notification even if its closed with workmanager and flutter_local_notification and its work fine with emulator , but when i build the an APK i do not receive any notification
i tried to change the icon but nothing happened

i think the problem with permissions  or adding something to androidmanifest.xml 
 and this is a part of the code

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'choosingpage.dart';
import 'package:workmanager/workmanager.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

const simplePeriodicTask = "simplePeriodicTask";
// flutter local notification setup
void showNotification( v, flp) async {
  var android = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channel id', 'channel NAME', 'CHANNEL DESCRIPTION',
      priority: Priority.High, importance: Importance.Max);
  var iOS = IOSNotificationDetails();
  var platform = NotificationDetails(android, iOS);
  await flp.show(0, 'Message from Manager', '$v', platform,
      payload: '$v');
}



Future<void> main() async {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Workmanager.initialize(callbackDispatcher, isInDebugMode: true); //to true if still in testing lev turn it to false whenever you are launching the app
  await Workmanager.registerPeriodicTask("5", simplePeriodicTask,
      existingWorkPolicy: ExistingWorkPolicy.replace,
      frequency: Duration(minutes: 15),//when should it check the link
      initialDelay: Duration(seconds: 5),//duration before showing the notification
      constraints: Constraints(
        networkType: NetworkType.connected,
      ));


  runApp(new MaterialApp(


  // routes: {
  //   // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
  //   '/': (context) => firstpage(),
  //   // When navigating to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen widget.
  //   'allresult': (context) => allresult(),
  //   'userpage': (context) => userpage(hi),
  // },
  //     initialRoute: 'allresult',
    theme:
        ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.red, accentColor: Colors.yellowAccent),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: choosingpage(),
    ));

}
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager.executeTask((task, inputData) async {
     var box ;
     String username;
     String userpass;
     String company;
    final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    Hive.init(dir.path);
    box = await Hive.openBox('app_data');
    username = box.get('usernamelogin');
    userpass = box.get('userpasslogin');

    company = box.get('company');
     print(username);
    print(userpass);

     print(company);

    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flp = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    var android = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var iOS = IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initSetttings = InitializationSettings(android, iOS);
    flp.initialize(initSetttings);
    var map = Map<String, dynamic>();

      map['user'] = username;
       map['pas'] = userpass;
        map['com'] = company;


        var url ="web site" ;

    final response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: map);
       var userdata = json.decode(response.body);

       print(userdata["notf"]);
       String mass=userdata["notf"];
       String datenotf=userdata["datenotf"];

        print(userdata);


      //  if(mass!=""){
      //   showNotification("$mass", flp);
      // } else {
      // print("no messgae");
      // }
      if(mass!=""){
        showNotification("$mass", flp);
      }
       if(datenotf!=""){
        showNotification("$datenotf", flp);
      } 



    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is an issue only with the apk release build it may have to do with the minification done by ProGuard/R8. You can disable minification as a test by passing the "--no-shrink" flag to the flutter build command.

i.e.:
flutter build apk --noshrink

**Release build configuration**

Before creating the release build of your app (which is the default setting when building an APK or app bundle) you will likely need to customise your ProGuard configuration file as per this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#keep-code) and add the following line:

-keep class com.dexterous.** { *; }

After doing so, rules specific to the GSON dependency being used by the plugin will also needed to be added. These rules can be found [here](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg). The example app has a consolidated Proguard rules (proguard-rules.pro) file that combines these together for reference [here](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/master/flutter_local_notifications/example/android/app/proguard-rules.pro).

⚠️ Ensure that you have configured the resources that should be kept so that resources like your notification icons aren't discarded by the R8 compiler by following the instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#keep-resources). Without doing this, you might not see the icon you've specified in your app's notifications. The configuration used by the example app can be found [here](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/master/flutter_local_notifications/example/android/app/src/main/res/raw/keep.xml) where it is specifying that all drawable resources should be kept, as well as the file used to play a custom notification sound (sound file is located [here](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/master/flutter_local_notifications/example/android/app/src/main/res/raw/slow_spring_board.mp3)).

[Link to Documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)